# How can I move elements out of a boxed slice, consuming the slice in the process?

Tags: rust

For example:

```
struct T(u32); // No Copy implementation

fn consume(t: T) {}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![T(1), T(2)];
    let s = v.into_boxed_slice();
    // Get a Box<[T]> from somewhere and consume it:
    for t in s {
        consume(t);
    }
}
```

results in the compiler error:

```
error[E0277]: `[T]` is not an iterator
 --> src/main.rs:9:14
  |
9 |     for t in s {
  |              ^ `[T]` is not an iterator
  |
  = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for `[T]`
  = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::boxed::Box<[T]>`
```

I could use `s.into_vec()` to construct a `Vec` from the boxed slice, and then consume the vector. That would be close to a no-op performance-wise, but is there a more elegant way?

Comment: What's inelegant about `into_vec`?

Comment: @PeterHall: Because it constructs a vector just to deconstruct it immediately, without giving the compiler any new information. It's not horribly inelegant, but it seems weird that I can't move things out of an owned container without detours.

Comment: Few people use `Box<[T]>`, so it hasn't received as much care and attention as `Vec<T>`. It certainly would be possible to implement `IntoIterator` for `Box<[T]>`, it's just that nobody bothered to do so yet.

Comment: You can't move elements out of a slice so I think you have to use `into_vec`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a Rust issue for supporting this directly: [Box<[T]> should have an IntoIter implementation](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/59878).

The best thing you can do in stable Rust is convert it into a `Vec`:

```rust
let v = Vec::from(s);
for t in v {
    consume(t);
}
```

I don't believe that this will have a performance downside as the conversion to the `Vec` basically adds a single `usize`.

---

If you know the length of the slice at compile time, you can convert the slice into a `Box<[T; N]>` and then use [`array::IntoIter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/array/struct.IntoIter.html) to iterate:

```rust
use std::convert::TryInto;

let a: Box<[T; 2]> = match s.try_into() {
    Ok(a) => a,
    Err(_) => panic!("Not length 2"),
};

for t in std::array::IntoIter::new(*a) {
    consume(t);
}
```