# Rc<[T]> try_unwrap into Vec<T>

Tags: pointers, rust, smart-pointers

Is there some function like `try_unwrap` that would allow me to obtain a slice from `Rc`?
Or do I have to manually check the reference count and use unsafe pointer magic to achieve this?

Edit: it looks like there is no such thing. I also cannot just extract pointer and the call `forget` because that would leak the counters. What should I do in such case?

Comment: Related: [How can I move elements out of a boxed slice, consuming the slice in the process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42540227/how-can-i-move-elements-out-of-a-boxed-slice-consuming-the-slice-in-the-process)

Comment: Would [`into_raw`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.into_raw) paired with [`decrement_strong_count`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.decrement_strong_count) work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no builtin function, but you can use the code below:

```rust
fn rc_slice_to_vec<T>(rc: Rc<[T]>) -> Result<Vec<T>, Rc<[T]>> {
    use std::mem::ManuallyDrop;
    if Rc::strong_count(&rc) != 1 {
        return Err(rc);
    }
    let len = rc.len();
    let mut v = Vec::with_capacity(len);
    let rc_raw = Rc::into_raw(rc);
    unsafe { 
        // SAFETY:
        // * rc_raw is trivially valid for a read of `len * size_of::<T>()`
        // * the pointer derived from `v` is trivially valid for a write of
        //   the same number of bytes
        // * both pointers are properly aligned, they're derived from types
        //   that can hold `T`
        // * the regions are from different allocations so they can't overlap
        std::ptr::copy_nonoverlapping(
            rc_raw.cast::<T>(),
            v.spare_capacity_mut().as_mut_ptr() as *mut T, // ≙ MaybeUninit::slice_as_mut_ptr
            len
        );
        // SAFETY:
        // * `len` is the capacity we requested so it's <= capacity
        // * we've initialized the elements 0..len
        v.set_len(len);
        // SAFETY:
        // * `ManuallyDrop<T>` has the same size and alignment as `T`
        // * `rc_raw` is derived from `rc` which is a `Rc`
        // * elements are wrapped in `ManuallyDrop` so `T`s `Drop` implementation
        //   is not invoked (we've moved the elements to `v`)
        Rc::decrement_strong_count(rc_raw as *const [ManuallyDrop<T>]);
    }
    Ok(v)
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=01b51bad9312ecf0c5361281d65387c6)

Comment: Actually this function performs a copy, which defeats the whole point of `try_unwrap`. Wouldn't it be better to just do `Vec::from_raw_parts`

Comment: Pointers created with `Rc::into_raw` do not fulfill the requirements to be passed to `Vec::from_raw_parts`. Take a look at how [`Rc::new` is implemented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#379-401) which should make that point apparent. The allocation does not only contain the slice! @alagris

Comment: Also just to be a little more precise, this does perform a *bitwise* copy of the values, but semantically it's a **move**, not a copy.

Comment: well, in my particular case `T` is a primitive type that is `Copy`. So this implementation is actually no better than `as_slice().to_vec()`. Actually I didn't mean to pass `Vec::from_raw_parts(Rc::into_raw(rc), len)` but rather `Vec::from_raw_parts(rc.deref().as_mut_ptr(), len)`. That should be a much better function i think.

Comment: `Vec::from_raw_parts(rc.deref().as_mut_ptr(), len, len)` is immediate UB just the same since you did not adhere to the safety requirements of `from_raw_parts`. There is no way to end up with a `Vec<T>` without moving the items out of the `Rc<[T]>`

Comment: Note that this requirement to bitwise copy is no different from regular `Rc::try_unwrap` which also [copies the data](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/alloc/rc.rs.html#909-929) (in this case with `ptr::read`).

Comment: That's disappointing. I ended up writing my own `Rc` because I need to handle very large arrays of `f32`. Btw, I took at look at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.from_raw_parts again but I don't really understand why `Vec::from_raw_parts(rc.deref().as_mut_ptr(), len, len)` would violate any of the requirements. Is it because `RcBox` stores both counter and the value as part of one continuous memory allocation and it's impossible to deallocate reference counters without deallocating the value itself? I wrote my own Rc that keeps the two as separate allocations.

Comment: `rc.deref().as_mut_ptr()` is not something allocated with the `Global` allocator (only a part of such). `len` * `T` is not the whole `size` the allocation that belongs to it was allocated with, ... Basically yes, `RcBox` is a single allocation, and it being an implementation detail doesn't improve the situation either. But there is likely no need to code your own `Rc`, you can just use a `Rc<Box<[T]>>` for a cheap move and separated allocations. `Box<[T]>` also can be converted to `Vec<T>` basically for free.